# Is it possible to get Codelense for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Previously i had Visual Studio 2013 and linked the Codelense-Feature.
Is there a way to install it in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition?

Example for Codelense in Visual Studio 2013:

[image: Codelense-Example in Visual Studio 2013]

[Visual Studio 2015 Version-Comarison](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx)
[image: Visual Studio 2015 Version-Comarison]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to install Codelense by installing the latest SSDT preview for Visual Studio 2015 from the link below. I can confirm that it works with VS 2015 Community Edition Update 1-3 (Update 3 is the latest at the moment)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/mt186501

**You have to install the optional Service within the SSDT-Installer:**

- SQL Server Integration Service (Thanks to Vaclav Elias)

[image: Installer]

**If all three are unticked it doesn´t install Codelense!**

Comment: May I ask where you got this information from? I have worked on this feature and can confirm that there is absolutely no dependency on SQL.

Comment: I have got Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (CE), yesterday installed some Visual Studio KB but also the SQL Server 2016 Management Studio from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx and got the Codelense inside my Visual Studio 2015 CE, not sure the real cause but it is cool!!! I installed only SQL Server Integration Services and the default grayed one.